# Why is a TR visible when not in DOM?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.4

Why is a `tr` element that hasn't been added to the DOM considered visible in jQuery, but a `div` is not?

```
$('<tr></tr>').is(':visible')     // returns true
$('<div></div>').is(':visible')   // returns false
```

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2.  I tested this in Firefox 5, IE 9, Chrome 12, and Safari 5, and Opera 11.5.

**Resolution**

I've written a workaround to use in my application until I can upgrade to a more recent version of jQuery:

```
$('<tr></tr>').is('body *:visible')     // returns false
$('<div></div>').is('body *:visible')   // returns false
```

Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: I can't reproduce this in any of the jQuery versions available on jsfiddle, on Firefox 5. Both are `false`.

Comment: @tjm: I can reproduce it with 1.4.2, but jsfiddle doesn't have that version.

Comment: Weird. A bug in 1.4.2 perhaps? (Or perhaps bug isn't the right word; but an *inconsistency* certainly).

Comment: Sidenote: Try to update your jQuery to 1.6.2 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`visible` doesn't mean that you can physically see it. It will still be true even when your eyes are closed, for example.

The node itself has no concept that the browser only renders *one* DOM tree.

It has no attributes set whereby an HTML browser would treat it as "invisible", therefore it is "visible"... even if it's not part of the one node tree that the browser's actually rendering.

You might also ask how `$('<b>Bold text</b>')` can possibly be bold, or have *any* graphical formatting, when it cannot be seen.

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

> Elements can be considered hidden for
>   several reasons:
>
> - They have a CSS display value of none.
> - They are form elements with type="hidden".
> - Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
> - An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

Clearly none of these are true here.

I cannot explain why Dunhamzzz is able to produce a different result, though! It may be related somehow to the `iframe` in which the fiddle runs.

---

### Update

OK, [jsfiddle.net has nothing to do with it](http://tom.kera.name/so-6597692-jQ144.html).

However, [I *can* reproduce this with 1.4.2](http://tom.kera.name/so-6597692-jQ142.html).

So one or both of them is wrong. Given the inconsistent behaviour of `tr` vs `div`, I'd suggest that 1.4.2 is incorrect (there were [a number of hidden-item-related changes in 1.4.4](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/11/11/jquery-1-4-4-release-notes/)) and that the documentation is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Do a fiddle, [both are false for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/zhEYp/) Which is to be expected as they haven't been placed in the DOM yet and therefore have no styles/visibility applied to them.

Comment: It's _not_ to be expected. [There is nothing about the `:visible` selector which checks for DOM inclusion](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/). (Though I cede that it is happening!)

Comment: Fiddle obsession hits; 1.4.2 _does_ reproduce it. :)